# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una tarea paralela de la siguiente manera en Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data

Me gustaría poder llevar a cabo una tarea como la que aparece en la imagen.

1. Una función que lee un dataset
2. Aplica alguna transformación
3. Realiza en paralelo una exportación del dataset a csv y mientras el csv se guarda devuelva el dataset como pd.DataFrame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? La pregunta es relevante, puesto que depende de si la causa es que estás en un entorno interactivo en el que quieres recuperar "el prompt" mientras se guarda el csv, o que el dataframe es enorme y tarda mucho en guardarse, etc. En general hay dos vías para hacerlo y es usar hilos o bien multiproceso. Con hilos tienes el problema del GIL, que causará que no obtengas mucha ganancia de tiempo si la tarea es intensiva en CPU. Con procesos no hay gil, pero hay que transmitir el dataframe al otro proceso, lo que será una sobrecarga.

Comment: @abulafia Quiero hacer eso para pintar el resultado del dataframe en una interfaz mientras en segundo plano se realiza el guardado del dataset en csv.